# Tailwind css font-family classes are not rendering as they should

Tags: css, tailwind-css

**Context**

I want to use tailwind css 3.0 in one of my vuejs 2 project. I correctly setup tailwind css to make it work in my project.

**What i try to do**

The first thing i wanted from tailwind css is the font management. The first thing i tried to do is use the font family modifier `font-sans` as it is explained [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family). so in a given div i added the classes : `font-sans` and `font-semibold` which simply is a font-size modifier.

**What i expected**

So if i go back on the tailwind css website they show us the result of adding the `font-sans` class to text [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family), and it looks like that (to be precise all the classes applyed on this text are : `font-sans text-lg font-medium text-gray-900`) :

[image]

So i did the same on my project and i obtain this :

[image]

**The problem**

We can easily see that those two sentences doesn't have the same style (the font-family is the problem). And i don't understand why they havn't the same rendering as they have the exact same classes.

thank you for any time spent on this problem, if you need more precisions just ask me

Comment: What font-family are you using? Tailwind site has `Inter var` as its first font, what do you have?

Comment: I'm not using any particular font-family. I supposed that using the generated class `font-sans` would give me the same rendering as it is on the tailwind css website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tailwind site uses custom font for their site (specifically `Inter var`):

```
font-family: Inter var,ui-sans-serif,system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Arial,Noto Sans,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol,Noto Color Emoji
```

If you want to customize it you can do it in `tailwind.config`:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      'sans': ['ui-sans-serif', 'system-ui', ...],
      'serif': ['ui-serif', 'Georgia', ...],
      'mono': ['ui-monospace', 'SFMono-Regular', ...],
      'display': ['Oswald', ...],
      'body': ['"Open Sans"', ...],
    }
  }
}
```